# powershell to edit multiple users phone numbers in active directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am looking to update every user in AD both Telephone numbers from the general tab and pager, mobile and fax.  What I am looking to update is any user in our AD from +44 (0) +44 0

I have tried with the following but did not work but can't see why

```
$UserSplat = @{
    LDAPFilter = "(|(homephone=*)(othermobile=*)(mobile=*))"
    Properties = @('homephone', 'othermobile', 'mobile')
    SearchBase = 'OU=NoAdm,OU=Users,DC=xxxxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=net'
}

Get-ADUser @UserSplat | ForEach-Object {
    $CurrentUser = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Name        = $_.Name 
        HomePhone   = (-join $_.homephone) -replace '\s'
        OtherMobile = (-join $_.othermobile) -replace '\s'
        Mobile      = (-join $_.mobile) -replace '\s'
    }

    $CurrentUser
    
    if ($CurrentUser.homephone -notmatch '^\(0)') {
        $_ | Set-ADUser -Replace @{homephone = "0$($CurrentUser.HomePhone)" } -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Comment: You can begin by reading the documentation on `Get-ADuser` and `Set-ADuser`

Comment: I formatted the code you posted, but had to make some guesses as to where whitespace had been mangled - please review and verify that this is indeed the code you're trying to run

Comment: `'^\(0)'` <-- this is not a valid regex pattern, should be `'^\(0\)'` (if you're looking for `(0)` at the start of the string)

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately can't test this, I believe `-LDAPFilter` should be capable of filtering only those users that actually have their `homephone`, `othermobile` and `mobile` attributes starting with `+44 (0)` hence I added that to save a step. I also left the `-WhatIf` switch to be sure the script is doing what is supposed to do.

```
$startsWith = '+44 (0)'
$UserSplat = @{
    LDAPFilter = "(|(homephone=$startsWith*)(othermobile=$startsWith*)(mobile=$startsWith*))"
    Properties = @('homephone', 'othermobile', 'mobile')
    SearchBase = 'OU=NoAdm,OU=Users,DC=xxxxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=net'
}

$startsWith = [regex]::Escape($startsWith)
foreach($user in Get-ADUser @UserSplat)
{
    $replaceHash = @{}
    foreach($prop in 'homephone', 'othermobile', 'mobile')
    {
        if(($replace = $user.$prop) -match $startsWith) {
            $replaceHash[$prop] = $replace -replace '\(|\)'
        }
    }
    Set-ADUser $user -Replace $replaceHash -WhatIf
}
```

Comment: woops, thanks Theo :)

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try on my test vm

Comment: thanks finally got to test this and pleased to report all working :) thanks so much for help

Comment: @allenmur happy to help, you could consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it could solve your problem :)